# LARAVEL General error: 1364 Field 'insert_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

> General error: 1364 Field 'insert_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into tools (position, code_tool, updated_at, created_at) values (1, wewr3, 2020-01-26 08:51:11, 2020-01-26 08:51:11))",

**Dentro de mi formulario poseo una tabla donde agrego campos dinámicamente.** esos campos contienen información necesaria para la fabricación de una pieza dentro de esta tabla dinámica participan estas entidades:**PIEZA-HERRAMIENTA con una relación de muchos a muchos y HERRAMIENTA-INSERTO relación de uno a muchos.**

**Entiendo que primero se debe crear el inserto, luego crear la herramienta ya que la tabla tools tiene un campo insert_id y finalmente crear la pieza asociando las herramientas.**

En mi controlador intento lo siguiente:

controlador PieceController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();                              

                $program = Program::create($request->all());
                $gag = Gag::create($request->all());


                foreach ($request->addmore as $key => $value)
                {    
                   //creo el inserto              
                   Insert::create($value);

                   //luego creo la herramienta y su inserto
                   Tool::create($value);

                   //finalmente asocio las herramientas a la pieza 
                   $piece->tools()->attach($request->get('addmore[0]'));                 
                }  

                $piece = $program->piece()->create([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],
                    'gag_id'       => $gag->id
                ]);             

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
```

formulario:

```
<div class="row">
    {!! Form::model($piece, [
        'route' => $piece->exists ? ['admin.pieces.update', $pieces->id] : 'admin.pieces.store',   
        'method' => $piece->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!} 

     <div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="box box-primary">            
            <div class="box-header with-border ">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del Legajo</h3>     
            </div>  
            <div class="box-body">  

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">  
                <tr>
                    <th>Posición</th>
                    <th>Herramienta</th>                 
                    <th>Inserto</th>                 
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][position]" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control select2" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][code_tool]" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][code_insert]" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" /></td>                      
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add More</button></td>  
                </tr>  
            </table> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

**¿Como deberia recorrer de manera correcta mi foreach en controlador?**

**ACTUALIZADO**

Es asi como tengo relacionados mis modelos

model piece:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Piece extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'program_id', 'gag_id', 'denomination', 'code', 'part_piece', 'time', 'observation'
    ];    

    public function program()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
    }  

    public function gag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gag::class);
    } 

    public function tools() 
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tool::class)->withTimestamps();
    }   

}
```

model tool:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tool extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'insert_id', 'position', 'code_tool', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];   

    public function inserts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Insert::class);
    }    

    public function pieces()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Piece::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

model insert:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Insert extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'code_insert', 'quality', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];

    public function tool()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Insert::class);
    } 
}
```

model program:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Program extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name_program','number_program','part_program'
   ]; 

   public function piece()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Piece::class);
    }
}
```

he agregado   dd($request->all()); al metodo store:

```
 array:13 [
  "_token" => "Mvq8DmWxaZHVN5fxWPzk1iM9NkEgMmexVDDR4gtO"
  "denomination" => "2"
  "code" => "63680"
  "part_piece" => "6"
  "addmore" => array:1 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "position" => "121"
      "code_tool" => "11wee"
      "code_insert" => "223ffr"
      "quality" => "mmt4"
    ]
  ]
  "name_program" => "laudantium"
  "number_program" => "453"
  "part_program" => "1"
  "number_gag" => "14"
  "diameter" => "37"
  "type_gag" => "EXTERIOR"
  "category_gag" => "CON TOPE"
  "time" => "09:58:41"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

No estas mandando el `insert_id` cuando creas el piece.
Agrega un input en el formulario, agregalo en el controlador o en la migración podes poner `->nullable()` en el campo `insert_id` para que pueda quedar vacio

```
$piece = $program->piece()->create([
    'insert_id'    => 'INSERT_ID',
    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
    'code'         => $request['code'],
    'time'         => $request['time'],
    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],
    'gag_id'       => $gag->id
]);
```

Comment: puedes revisar mi actualización? si observas el insert_id esta en el modelo tool, insisto seguramente no estoy recorriendo adecuadamente el foreach, precisamente acá: ```  foreach ($request->addmore as $key => $value)```

Comment: ahi lo estoy leyendo

Comment: Estaría faltándome la definición de la relación en el Model `Program`  
quizá ahi esta el problema

Comment: ok lo actualice nuevamente, Agregue  model program

Comment: `get('addmore[0]')` esto dudo que funcione
te recomiendo hacer un `dd($request->all());` al inicio del metodo te va a ayudar a entender como estan llegando los datos.  `addmore` Deberia ser un array.

Comment: despues no encuentro donde estas definiendo la variable `$piece`

Comment: he agregado ```dd($request->all());``` al principio del metodo, que me puedes decir de addmore? de que manera puedo guardar los datos del inserto que le pertence a la herramienta para luego asociarla a la pieza?

Comment: creo que hay muchisimas cosas ahi que deberias revisar. 
Fijate como se hace el [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) y no estoy viendo dentro de los fillables un campo que se llame program_id y tampoco donde estas definiendo $piece

Comment: que te muestra el `dd()`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103750/discussion-between-maru-amallo-and-rodrigo-ruiz).

Comment: @ Maru Amallo el campo program_id esta en el modelo Piece basicamente necesito resolver esto:  como guardar los datos del inserto que le pertence a la herramienta para luego asociarla a la pieza?

Comment: continuamos por el chat

Comment: Insert_id no debe estar en el modelo tools, debe estar en el modelo pieza ... a menos que tanto la pieza como la herramienta, les estes pasando su id manualmente entonces deberas tener do campos y diferenciarlos... saludos

Answer (score 0):

Este error se relaciona con:

- los campos que tienes en la propiedad `$fillable` del modelo
- la declaración de campos de la tabla asociada, sin un valor por defecto
- los datos que usas para crear un registro del modelo o la falta de los mismos (con una **asignación masiva**)

Me explico, imaginemos que tienes la tabla `foos` con los campos:

- id
- name
- description

Creas un modelo `Foo` como este:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
   ]; 
}
```

Y tienes la siguiente migración:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFoosTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('foos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('foos');
    }
}
```

Cuando vas a usar el método `Foo::create($arrDatos);` para guardar un registro en la tabla `foos`, es decir crear un registro mediante **asignación masiva**, ***el modelo espera un dato para cada uno de los campos que has definido en `$fillable` salvo que el campo correspondiente tenga asignado un valor por defecto cuando se creo la tabla***. Entonces, con la migración anterios, si tu formulario no envía el campo "name" o "description" y *no los añades de alguna forma* antes de invocar `create`, por ejemplo, así *(después de usar un FormRequest)*:

```
Foo::create($request->validated());
```

Obtienes un error como el mencionado.
Veamos, por ejemplo, si la descripción no tiene valor en el formulario y no hay una validación previa de contenido requerido:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'description' doesn't have a default value ...
```

La forma de solventarlo en este caso sería asignar un valor por defecto a los campos en la migración (lo que incluye declararlos nulos por defecto):

```
Schema::create('foos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 100)->default('Foo-' . time());
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

También puede comprobarse si los campos necesarios están presentes antes de invocar `create` bien en el controlador o bien en un *FormRequest* previamente (recomendable).

La documentación sobre la asignación masiva en Laravel y uso de `$fillable` está aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts